# Set alloy UI timepicker timeslots

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-aui, alloy-ui

I have an alloy ui timepicker in my form. I want to only display Hours in the Input Fields. **But the problem is Alloy UI divides Timeslots in 30 minutes each.** So thats my input fields displays same hour 2 times

```
A.use('aui-timepicker', function(A) {
    new A.TimePicker({
        trigger : 'input#<portlet:namespace/>endTime',
        mask : '%H',
        popover : {
            zIndex : 1011
        },
        on : {
            selectionChange : function(event) {
                console.log(event.newSelection)
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**With Minutes & Time**

- 00:00
- 00:30
- 01:00
- 01:30

**Only Hours**

- 00
- 00
- 01
- 01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [AlloyUI TimePicker API docs](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.TimePicker.html) do not document any feature to change the step between time elements besides the [`values` attribute](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.TimePicker.html#attr_values). The solution is to set the `values` attribute to the values you want. One simple way to do this is to create an array that has the values you want:

```
var values = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
  values.push(i.toString());
}
```

Then just set the `values` attribute to the created array:

```
YUI().use('aui-timepicker', function(Y) {
  new Y.TimePicker({
    /* Your code here... */
    mask: '%H',
    values: values
  });
});
```

Here's a runnable example:

```js
var values = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
  values.push(i.toString());
}

YUI().use('aui-timepicker', function(Y) {
  new Y.TimePicker({
    mask: '%H',
    trigger: '#input',
    values: values,
    popover: {
      zIndex: 1
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.alloyui.com/2.0.0/aui/aui-min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.alloyui.com/2.0.0/aui-css/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<input id="input" />
```